# Can't get passenger to load after rails cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, capistrano

After several hours of setting up my apache linode slice, and getting rails and passengers configured, I'm getting the dreaded "no such file to load -- bundler/setup" passenger error. Here's a screencap:

[image: Screen cap]

As for where stuff is located on the server:

which ruby = /usr/local/bin/ruby

which gem = /usr/local/bin/gem

which passenger = /usr/local/bin/passenger

gem list -d bundler:

```
bundler (1.0.15)
    Authors: André Arko, Terence Lee, Carl Lerche, Yehuda Katz
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/bundler
    Homepage: http://gembundler.com
    Installed at: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

    The best way to manage your application's dependencies
```

However, running irb in the app results in:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'bundler'
LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler
```

Any suggestions?